# react use font awesome dynamically

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I'm trying to use font awesome based on variable.

```
 {var icon = 'FaFolder'}
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={(icon)} />
```

This is the error: Could not find icon {prefix: "fas", iconName: "faFolder"}

Of course I'm importing everything, and when I hardcoded the string instead of the var it works perfect.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { FaFolder } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
```

I know that if i refer the var to the FaFolder I'm importing like this

```
var icon = FaFolder
```

it will work but I have more than 10 icons I'm using and staring refer each one it is not efficient.
Any one knows how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work you have two options:

- Option 1: Import font-awesome icons from CDN and use them not in the react component (this will allow you to store the icon name in the db and than you can add dynamically a className to `<i>` tags
- Option 2: call the full icon name in an array: `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fab", "github"]} />`
- Option 3: You have to pre-import in you index.js **ALL** the icons you need in your whole project in your index.js or App.js and then you can use them by retrieving their names from the db.

```
//App.js
//....
//React imports
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core' //allows later to just use icon name to render-them
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faCoffee)
```

```
//Other_file.js
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'

export const Beverage = () => (
  <div>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="check-square" /> //Put here your icon string
    Your <FontAwesomeIcon icon="coffee" /> is hot and ready!
  </div>
)
```

Comment: The full react reference here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react

Comment: The third option worked for me just fine. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
{var icon = ['fa','folder']}
 <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} />
```

or

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fa','folder']} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your problem is that `FaFolder` being imported isn't a string. It's an object. You could consider adding `FaFolder` to state or importing it in the file you'll use it and using it instead. Something like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { FaFolder } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

export default function Component(props) {
  let icon = FaFolder;
  return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={(icon)} />
}
```

Comment: Well the var icon I wrote in my app it is not really a var it's a state coming from the DB containing the icon name. Starting to do what you saying for every option I have it's not efficient.